# How to Serialize or Save Multiple Forms to Single File

Tags: vb.net

Essentially I'm creating a D&D character sheet with 9 forms, 6 of which will be saved. I need to save every TextBox in each of those 6 forms. I haven't tried Serialization yet as I haven't found an especially good guide that clarifies exactly what I need to do yet, and at this point it's fairly confusing to me. I have, however, tried saving to a file and writing back when the file is opened. This works for one form, but I'm almost certain that it won't work for multiple forms given the way that the code is written.

```
Dim SaveCharacter As StreamWriter
        If txtName.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("In order to save, you must at least enter a name for your character.", "Error: No Name Entered")
        Else
            SaveCharacterAs.ShowDialog()
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveCharacterAs.FileName, "")
            Try
                For Each cnt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
                    SaveCharacter = File.AppendText(SaveCharacterAs.FileName)
                    SaveCharacter.WriteLine(cnt.Text)
                    SaveCharacter.Close()
                Next
                For Each cnt In frmAttributeRoller.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
                    SaveCharacter = File.AppendText(SaveCharacterAs.FileName)
                    SaveCharacter.WriteLine(cnt.Text)
                    SaveCharacter.Close()
                Next
```

The above code is what I have for writing to a file. I was thinking of trying to save the file to a .txt file with the name of the character that's entered in the form, and for each subform that I'm saving, create a separate .txt file with the character name concatenated with the form name, then write code to open all of those files in the correct forms, but that could get messy if the user selects the wrong file to start with. Is there a better way to save multiple forms to one file without serializing? Is serializing my best bet?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are not saving (nor serializing) forms or controls, just some text.  A collection of class objects can easily be serialized to one file.  Object Oriented Programming is a wonderful thing

Comment: You should also know that blindly writing control text to a file is fairly fragile: a small change to the UI could cause their order to change making previously saved files incompatible

Comment: So I can serialize each textbox in ALL of my forms to one file, like 
Dim cnt as Me.Controls.OfType(Of textBox)?

Comment: No.  Serializing requires a class.  Thats a good thing because it helps organize the data.  Those TBs represent things like Name, Power, Health, Weapon etc.  The class stores those as properties and a collection of them is the whole gang.  The collection can be serialized by various means

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion.  Create a DataSet with tables that describe your character sheet fields.  Then create an instance of that DataSet and add a record with default (mostly blank) values to the table.

Now you can bind the columns to text boxes like this.  (I'm doing this from memory, so forgive me if it doesn't compile - it should at least point you in the right direction

```
Dim ds As New CharacterDataSet ' Whatever you call your dataset
Dim bs As New BindingSource(ds, ds.CharacterTable.TableName)
bs.MoveFirst()
' Note, if you end up having more than one record, you can use bs.Filter 
' to select which record the BindingSource points to.

txtCharacterName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "CharacterName") ' Where CharacterName is the name of the column in the table
cboCharacterRace.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bs, "Race") ' For a ComboBox
```

Also, if you want to be more robust with your column names in the DataBindings.Add, you can do something like `ds.CharacterTable.CharacterNameColumn.ColumnName`. That way, you can't accidentally misspell the column name in the binding.

Now you can use DataSet.WriteXML to write out the the whole dataset in one shot.